# How to stop docker pull

Tags: docker

I have just started learning docker. In a tutorial, I saw the docker pull command which can be used like `docker pull container-name` to pull the respective container from the docker hub repository.

But in case, if you cancel the pull by using "Ctrl + C", it is exiting from the ongoing progress but not stopping the download which I was confirmed by using `nethogs` which is showing,
[image: Nethogs docker progress]

I searched in Google for the same. But I couldn't see any useful information regarding this. What is the right way of cancelling the docker pull? Please help.

Comment: you should restart the server process, see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6928

Comment: @user2915097 Great! It seems to be working. Can you write the same as an answer? So that i can accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no direct way to stop the ongoing process of docker pull as of now. You should restart the docker service by using,

```
sudo service docker restart
```

This will stop the ongoing pull of docker. For more details please check this github docker issue, https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6928

CAUTION: This command will stop all the running containers in the system

Comment: It really shocks me how many people consider this an acceptable solution... I can't just restart my production box because one pull failed, I have important things running on that box.  (not blaming you, I'm just absolutely shocked how often I see this suggested as a perfectly normal way to fix something)

Comment: @taxilian Probably I guess, there is no direct way to do that right now. So no other go other than a hack like this..

Comment: @Mr.Stranger will this restart\stop other containers?

Comment: @stackit yes unfortunately

Comment: so after a year any new method?

Comment: The doc says (from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) `Killing the docker pull process, for example by pressing CTRL-c while it is running in a terminal, will terminate the pull operation.` I noticed https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15489 and https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12874 on that subject

Answer (score 12):

It has been a year since the original post. UPDATE now if you just press Ctrl-C it will kill the actual docker pull process

This also works with the engine API. If you pull the container and read stream, destroying the read stream will stop the pull process