# Docker push already in progress

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I interrupted the following command : `docker push <user>/docker-whale`.

If I try running it again, I get :

```
Error response from daemon: push <user>/docker-whale is already in progress
```

I understand that the upload is still running in the background and that I only interrupted the client output. However, **is there a way to get it back?**

Also, if it's somehow stuck, how would you restart the push operation?

Comment: maybe what applies for pull also applies for push? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486032/how-to-stop-docker-pull/29486727#29486727

Comment: Thanks, `sudo service docker restart` actually worked : I can push again. That answers the second part of my question :) I'm still curious though, if you can check the push status after having stopped your client output..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens because you stopped pushing before it was finished.
You don't need to remove the containers; just restart boot2docker(or docker service).

```
Command maybe: 
    boot2docker restart (on Mac)
    service docker restart (on Linux)
```

After that, you can push your image again, Good Luck!

Comment: Or `docker-machine restart <machine-name>` if using `docker-machine`.

Comment: This gets the command unstuck ... however the  gcloud docker push reponame   fails to pickup where it left off and blindly, sadly just  starts over

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue on Mac, restart boot2docker and remove stopped container to fix it

```
boot2docker restart
```

```
docker ps -a | cut -c-12 | xargs docker rm
```